# Rails 4 has_many through: nested model id field is not inserted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have `visit` and `condition_value` models, associated with `has_many though` by `condition_visit`. 
Also, there are two other models: `condition_type` and `condition_name`. So basically there are a few conditions, each has a type and several values. When visit is created, the user chooses several values for every condition. There is also a `details` field for every condition.

I omitted the parts of code that seemed irrelevant.

```
class ConditionValue < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :condition_name
    has_many :visits
    has_many :condition_visits, through: :visits
end

class ConditionVisit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :visit
    belongs_to :condition_value
end

class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :condition_values, through: :condition_visits
    has_many :condition_visits, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :condition_visits, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

controller:

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
    ...
  def new
    @visit = Visit.new
    @visit.condition_visits.build
  end
   ...
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_visit
      @visit = Visit.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def visit_params
      params.require(:visit).permit( ... , condition_visits_attributes:
       [:details, condition_value_id:[]])
    end
end
```

view:

```
<div class="field">
<% ConditionType.all.each do |type| %>
  <% ConditionName.all.each do |v| %>
    <% if ConditionName.find_by(:name => v.name, :condition_type_id => type.id) %>
      <%= f.fields_for :condition_visits do |s| %>
        <%= v.name %> <%= s.collection_select(:condition_value_id, ConditionName.find_by(:name => v.name, :condition_type_id => type.id).condition_values, :id, :name, {:include_hidden => false}, :multiple => true) %>   
        Details: <%= s.text_field :details %>
      <% end %> 
    <% end %> 
    <br>
  <% end %>
  <hr>
<% end %>
```

The records are inserted into the DB, but only the `details` and `visit_id` fields, `condition_value_id` is NULL.

Log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eo9jxQqPk0UlPxAomDy4Njvf2+evVE/yySiaDFZMQM4Db5IvmTQ5fDK8wtxd5bTDMNfzfDBxXO+c+RdAXMjiMQ==", 
"visit"=>{"condition_visits_attributes"=>{
"0"=>{"condition_value_id"=>["2", "3"], "details"=>"1"}, 
"1"=>{"condition_value_id"=>["13"], "details"=>"2"}, 
"2"=>{"details"=>""}, "3"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"4"=>{"details"=>""}, "5"=>{"details"=>""}, "6"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"7"=>{"details"=>""}, "8"=>{"details"=>""}, "9"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"10"=>{"details"=>""}, "11"=>{"details"=>""}, "12"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"13"=>{"details"=>""}, "14"=>{"details"=>""}, "15"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"16"=>{"details"=>""}, "17"=>{"details"=>""}, "18"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"19"=>{"details"=>""}, "20"=>{"details"=>""}, "21"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"22"=>{"details"=>""}, "23"=>{"details"=>""}, "24"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"25"=>{"details"=>""}, "26"=>{"details"=>""}, "27"=>{"details"=>""}, 
"28"=>{"details"=>""}, "29"=>{"details"=>""}}, ..., 
"commit"=>"Create Visit", "doctor_id"=>"1", "patient_id"=>"14"}

....

SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "condition_visits" ("details", "visit_id",
    "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["details", "1"],
    ["visit_id", 236], ["created_at", "2016-03-22 13:20:46.254311"], 
    ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 13:20:46.254311"]]
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "condition_visits" ("details", "visit_id",
    "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["details", "2"],
    ["visit_id", 236], ["created_at", "2016-03-22 13:20:46.256021"], 
    ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 13:20:46.256021"]]
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "condition_visits" ("details", "visit_id",
    "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["details", ""], 
    ["visit_id", 236], ["created_at", "2016-03-22 13:20:46.257165"], 
    ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 13:20:46.257165"]]
...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In controller `params.permit` you used as `condition_value_ids[]` instead of `condition_value_id[]`

Comment: @GokulM thank you! The 'unpermitted parameter' warnings are gone but the `condition_value_id` fields are still not inserted..

Comment: Is there a column `condition_value_id` available in the table `condition_visits` please check it.

Comment: @GokulM yes, it's there https://yadi.sk/i/90ZJA0mDqPUv6

Comment: But your showing like this `INSERT INTO "condition_visits" ("details", "visit_id",
    "created_at", "updated_at")` kindly restart the server and check.

Comment: @GokulM yes, that is the problem. Just restarted the server and submitted the form, still `SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "condition_visits" ("details", "visit_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["details", "1"], ["visit_id", 239], ["created_at", "2016-03-22 13:48:18.680790"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 13:48:18.680790"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "condition_visits" ("details", "visit_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["details", "2"], ["visit_id", 239], ["created_at", "2016-03-22 13:48:18.682076"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-22 13:48:18.682076"]]
`